# XCode / Swift Beta 5: compiler sensitve to array shorthand array notation when target function is in different file

Tags: xcode, swift, beta

Why does this not compile?

When this code:

```
public struct Bar {
    var i: Int = 0
}


public struct Foo {}

extension Foo {


    public init(shorthand segments:[Bar]) {

        let s = segments[0..<2]
        let leftSegs = sliceFrom(segments) { (s:Bar) in true } // [Segment] does not conform to protocol Resliceable
    }
}
```

is in a separate file from this code:

```
protocol Resliceable {
    typealias Element

    var startIndex: Int { get }
    var endIndex: Int { get }
    subscript (index: Int) -> Element { get }
    subscript (subRange: Range<Int>) -> Slice<Element> { get }

    // extensions
    var count: Int { get }
    var capacity: Int { get }
    var isEmpty: Bool { get }
    var first: Element? { get }
    var last: Element? { get }
}

extension Array : Resliceable {}
extension Slice : Resliceable {}


func sliceFrom<S:Resliceable, T where T == S.Element>(s: S,
    from fn: (T) -> Bool) -> Slice<T> {

        for i in s.startIndex ..< s.endIndex {
            if fn(s[i]) { return s[i..<s.endIndex] }
        }

        return s[s.endIndex..<s.endIndex]
}
```

the swift compiler fails on this line:

```
let leftSegs = sliceFrom(segments) { (s:Bar) in true } // [Segment] does not conform to protocol Resliceable
```

I know need to write some longer prose for StackExchange to accept this as a valid question / post, and not simply a code dump.

So why does this not compile, and are there any work-arounds?

Comment: Please log a bug with Apple or it will never get fixed: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Did that, but thought posting might help save someone time (and it was frustrating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a compiler bug, but there are two work arounds:

1: Use the explicit Array syntax on the parameter of the calling function:

```
extension Foo {

    public init(explicit segments:Array<Bar>) {

        let s = segments[0..<2]
        let leftSegs = sliceFrom(segments) { (s:Bar) in true } // works, and causes both to work
    }
}
```

or

2:  Put all the code in the same file.